# Checkbox switcher VUE JS

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am trying to toggle this checkbox switcher. It is checked by default and when unchecked, a button should appear. During the checked, there should be a function to call. What am i missing?

```
<div class="form-group row m-b-10">
            <label class="col-form-label">Auto-Refresh:</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
              <div class="switcher switcher-success">
                                    <input type="checkbox" v-model="checked" name="switcher_checkbox_2" id="switcher_checkbox_2" checked="" value="1">
                                    <label for="switcher_checkbox_2"></label>
                                </div>

              </div>
              <div class="col-md-9" v-if="unchecked">
<button @click="logNode(namespace)" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" >Refresh</button>
</div>
              </div>
```

Comment: You use "checked" variable in v-model directive, and what is the value of "unchecked" variable? You can set v-if="!checked" and when you enter 0 -> your button will appear

Comment: @ValeriiVoronkov It worked! Thank You much! How do i add a function to the checkbox switcher? is it possible?

Comment: I can't understand what exactly you are trying to do with this. It seems you try to make you own logic of switcher. But why if you can use standard input[type="checkbox"]?

Comment: You can bind the method to the checked state...checked="{{ methodName }}". The method will handle the checked/not checked & you can write your business logic in that.

Comment: @ValeriiVoronkov What im trying to do is actually, when the switch is on, it will auto refresh my logs. Will a standard input work better?

Comment: I think standard input will be work better

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this codesandbox snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-9n75t)

Create methods for checkbox and button like below and define their own behaviour:

```
data: function() {
  return {
    checked: true
  };
},
methods: {
    logNode: function(myNamespace) {
      alert("button pressed");
    },
   toggle: function() {
      alert("checkbox triggered");
  }
}
```

Your html will look like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="form-group row m-b-10">
    <label class="col-form-label">Auto-Refresh:</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <div class="switcher switcher-success">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        v-model="checked"
        name="switcher_checkbox_2"
        id="switcher_checkbox_2"
        checked="true"
        value="1"
        v-on:change="toggle">
      <label for="switcher_checkbox_2"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9" v-if="!checked">
    <button @click="logNode(namespace)" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Refresh</button>
  </div>
</div>
```